# Why adding TextFiled from StatefulWidget won't appear?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new on Fultter and have the following issue. 
I have the following code that works as expected if I disable `ShowTextField()`, . If I enable `ShowTextField()`, line then some widgets will disappear and the TextField will not appear too.

1) What could be the reason for that ?

2) Is it correct to "call" StateFulWidget from StatelessWidget ?

Thanks in advance

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter layout demo2',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter layout demo3'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            titleSection,
            ShowTextField(), //Disable this line will make code work.
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShowTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowTextFieldState createState() => _ShowTextFieldState();
}

class _ShowTextFieldState extends State<ShowTextField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Hello world',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.)The error message says: 'An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded width.' Then this will work:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter layout demo2',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter layout demo3'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            titleSection,
            ShowTextField(), //Disable this line will make code work.
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShowTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowTextFieldState createState() => _ShowTextFieldState();
}

class _ShowTextFieldState extends State<ShowTextField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Container(
        width: 300.0, //<--- SET THE WIDTH
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Hello world',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

2.) Yes, perfectly fine.

Comment: Happy to hear, please mark it solved if it was useful.